# page redirects to www from http, why?

Tags: .htaccess, zend-framework, redirect

i just installed ssl certificate to our website and now i am trying to test/see it.
And those things happen.
1. i visit www.mydomain.com -> works fine. 
2. i visit mydomain.com -> goes to www.mydomain.com // stopped after removing the below code
3. i visit http://www.mydomain.com -> goes to www.mydomain.com
4. i visit https://www.mydomain.com -> webpage is not available.

i used to have this in my htaccess file but i removed it.

```
# Redirect non-www to www:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]>
```

i have no idea what is going on here.

i need to make it go to http:// all the time but it does not let me.

Site is in Zend Framework 1.12

if you need any more info, please comment below and i will provide.

Thanks

Comment: Do you even have a vhost setup to listen to SSL requests?

Comment: it is on a real server and my problem is not with the ssl, it is i cannot visit the site with http:// at the beginning

Comment: Does your server listen to port 80?

Comment: yes it does, it loads just fine

Comment: Are you using Chrome, which hides the `http://` in the address bar by default?

Comment: same thing happens with firefox as well

Comment: @Justin There is no such thing as a redirect from `http://example.com` to `example.com`. A request always needs to have a protocol. Your browser(s) must hide the `http://` part in the address bar. If your server spits out content when on http, but not when on https you have configured https incorrectly. Remember that https-requests go to port 443 instead of port 80. If you don't get an answer here, consider asking the question on webmasters.stackexchange.com. They might know how to properly configure it.

Comment: thanks a lot to all of you here trying to help me. i figured out what is wrong and will post it as an answer to help the ones who would like to use it.